# How to pass $_GET variables to a PHP script via the command line?

Tags: php, http, cgi

I am trying to create a webserver that serves PHP scripts. Currently, it works as follows:

1. The client requests /index.php?test=value
2. The server invokes `php index.php`
3. The server feeds the HTTP request headers as STDIN to the PHP process
4. The server reads the output of `php` from STDOUT and returns it to the client

All of this is working except that the parameters are not being passed to the PHP script because:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

returns:

> array(0) { }

How do `$_GET` parameters get passed to the PHP binary when it is invoked?

Comment: Which web server? How have you configured the web server? How have you configured PHP?

Comment: @jos: It's JetHTTP - one I wrote myself.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Which PHP binary are you using?  The CLI or CGI?  I suspect you need a [CGI version](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.commandline.php) of the binary for PHP to properly handle accept the environment variables and POST data if you pass that.

The `php-cgi` binary implements the CGI interface, which allows you to pass parameters on the command line:

```
php-cgi -f index.php left=1058 right=1067 class=A language=English
```

Which end up in `$_GET`:

```
Array
(
    [left] => 1058
    [right] => 1067
    [class] => A
    [language] => English
)
```

You may want to read up on how [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) works so you can implement that in your web server.

Ref: [RFC3875](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875)

Comment: Yup... sure enough. That was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface), the answer is to set the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable:

```
QUERY_STRING='user=foo&pass=bar&left=1234' php-cgi index.php
```

or in separate steps:

```
export QUERY_STRING='user=foo&pass=bar&left=1234'
php-cgi index.php
```

This works if you use the `php-cgi` command, because this is part of the CGI specification. The ordinary `php` command ignores this variable, but your script might use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass   php script.php test=asdf

```
$result = parse_args($argv,$argc,$help);
print_r($result);
```

If you are passing it to STDIN, you would need to read STDIN and parse the headers yourself.  REQUEST_URI would contain the data you need, and you could pass that.

Comment: I need the variables to be available in `$_GET` like they are when PHP is used under Apache.

Comment: All well and good until someone visits `/index.php?test=asdf;rm%20-rf%20/`

Comment: @dan: Don't worry, my webserver is smart enough to handle that.